# how to run my own js before FrameLoadEnd event in cefsharp

Tags: cefsharp

I would like to disable lazy image loading, so I want to run the following js code before FrameLoadEnd event is triggered.

```
$('#images img').each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("original"));
});
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can execute JavaScript in FrameLoadStart, you cannot access the DOM as it hasn't loaded yet, you can however subscribe to events like DOMContentLoaded. Practically speaking DOMContentLoaded and FrameLoadEnd are likely close in timing. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for looking into it. I would like save the page to pdf. But due to lazy image loading, some images in the pdf is blank.  Is there any solution?

Comment: How does executing JavaScript before FrameLoadEnd achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute JavaScript in FrameLoadStart, the event is fired very early in the page load lifecycle, before the DOM has loaded.

You execute JavaScript in FrameLoadStart to hook the DOMContentLoaded event, in practice this is often very similar in timing to FrameLoadEnd event.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    //Do something on DOM load.
});
```